# .NET MAUI Xaml: Flex layout inconsistency with images and text

Tags: xaml, maui

I have been extremely frustrated lately with xaml as I am unable to get form of consistency when  it comes to how Flex layout wraps. I haven't found another option for containing the content as I need both small, text sized images and normal text, and I need wrapping. The words don't go to the end of the page, and the images jump to seemingly random positions when I resize the image. Nothing I do has been able to fix this issue.

There are no line breaks in this, it chose to break after the image on its own:
[image: There are no line breaks in this, it chose to break after the image on its own]

This one is after I resize the window, the coin is no longer after the + and the other coin decided to go onto its own line:
[image: With this one the coin is no longer after the + and the other coin decided to go onto its own line]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some component or option that I don't know about that will magically solve my problems?

Here is the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjectName.MainPage">
    
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                Grid.Row="0">
                <FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap" AlignItems="Start" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Start" >
                    <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mazim liber delenit nec in, habeo veritus inciderint ex mel&#160;+" FontSize="16"/>
                    <Image Source="coin.png" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16" TranslationY="3"/>
                    <Label FontSize="16" Text="&#160;No facilis qualisque per, dolor omnes nec at, sanctus delectus omittantur mel eu. Possit commodo aliquando nam ea, nostro deserunt id qui, paulo regione inciderint nec te."/>
                    <Image Source="coin.png" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16" TranslationY="3"/>
                </FlexLayout>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you seem to expect the [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label) to break across the rows of the [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout), but that's actually impossible, because a *Label* is always a rectangle.

So, what happens instead is this: The *Label* takes as much space as it can, but eventually the text doesn't fit anymore, so it adds a line break and doesn't use the full width. The remaining space in the row is large enough for the *FlexLayout* to accommodate the *Image*, that's why you get this behavior.

***Note**: In your first picture the layout has two rows, in the second picture it has three rows.*

For this to *(sort of)* work with a *FlexLayout*, every word would need its own *Label*.

This is different to how you would do that sort of thing with HTML and CSS, because *Labels* in MAUI are not comparable to *paragraphs* in HTML. You might be able to achieve something like this with a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview) or using HTML in a *Label*.

Comment: Are there other components that I can use that will accomplish what I'm looking for or something similar?

Comment: Like I wrote, you can try a WebView and HTML or split the text into more labels.